# how i can fix it return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)? in python sklearn

Tags: python

[i got this errorValueError: could not convert string to float: '-8,01E+10'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow4fz.png)

this my code

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier

df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv',header=0,sep=';')

pipelines = {
    'lr':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression()),
    'rc':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RidgeClassifier()),
    'rf':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RandomForestClassifier()),
    'gb':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), GradientBoostingClassifier()),
}

X = df.drop('class', axis=1) # features
y = df['class'] # target value
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1234)

fit_models = {}
for algo, pipeline in pipelines.items():
    model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
    fit_models[algo] = model
```

and this my error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\Desktop\myProject\Pthon\everyCodepy\my.py", line 23, in 
model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 341, in fit
Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 303, in _fit
X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py", line 352, in **call**
return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 754, in _fit_transform_one
res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 702, in fit_transform
return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_data.py", line 730, in fit
return self.partial_fit(X, y, sample_weight)
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_data.py", line 766, in partial_fit
X = self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse=('csr', 'csc'),
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 421, in _validate_data
X = check_array(X, **check_params)
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 616, in check_array
array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core_asarray.py",
line 102, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
line 1899, in **array**
return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
File "C:\Users\Apuanudin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core_asarray.py",
line 102, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-8,01E+10'

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Add more details please. This is not how you post any answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a comma `,` somewhere in your data, probably in your `coords.csv`.

Instead of `8,0E+10` it must be `8.0E+10` for the `float()` conversion to work.

Comment: I've changed all commas to "." But not working to

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: same i got error  could not convert string to float: '-8,01E+10'

Comment: It seems that somewhere you still have a comma somewhere. Could you break the example down to something that is reproducible and also share the data that you are using?

Comment: this my csv file on github:

Comment: i got new error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Comment: Could you narrow down the row in your CSV file which is causing that error?